# A Good Start To Laravel Beginner

Tags: laravel

Now I'm using php in the ordinary way, After Some Searching I Knew that there is something called Laravel framework, I don't Know Any Thing About it ??? why we use laravel ?? is it for UI Enhancement "as Sliders,Drop-Down Boxs" or it makes php more easier in treating MySql or Mailing

I Need Also To Know How To Begin Installing it on Localhost & Learning it "Some Easy Tutorial"

Comment: StackOverflow is unsuitable to give tutorials. Try it out yourself, and ask specific questions here, or on one of the related sites. Also please format future questions in a way that it isn't in CamelCase.

Comment: I Don't Push a question in StackOverflow unless i've searched about it, and got some info but not useful or got no info, thanks for note

Comment: Hey @Naggar. I can understand your problem from which you have crossed earlier. Not much tutorials available. And, if available also, not so clear. Bit Confusing Man. I'm Banging My Head. It is very difficult, when nobody is there to help.

Comment: See All People. This question is closed because it is 'Unclear'. What you all can see top right side, total view is 11970 (in just 16 months), and will increase to 1,11,970 views, means how developer faced difficulty to learn what so called LARAVEL.

Comment: If you are looking for Laravel tutorials then Hackr.io has the best tutorials voted by the programming community: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-laravel

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Laravel` is a `Web Development Framework for PHP` and definition of framework from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework):

> A web application framework (WAF) is a software framework that is
>   designed to support the development of dynamic websites, web
>   applications, web services and web resources. The framework aims to
>   alleviate the overhead associated with common activities performed in
>   web development. For example, many frameworks provide libraries for
>   database access, templating frameworks and session management, and
>   they often promote code reuse. For a comparison of concrete web
>   application frameworks, see Comparison of web application frameworks.

In simple words, a framework lets you build applications easily with less effort because you don't have to write every code from scratch instead the framework provides tools/classes that you may use to write your project specific code easily.`Laravel` is one of the bests but not the only one, there are [others](http://www.phpframeworks.com/). You may also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301240/whats-a-php-framework-and-whats-a-good-one) as other answer stated.

The best way to learn the [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com/docs) is the manual on the website, so read the manual and also you may find articles on the web and also reading a good book will help you more.

Some Laravel Resources:

- [A list of places for resources](http://codecondo.com/laravel-news-resources-tutorials/)
- [Laravel-learning-resources](http://lorib.me/2013/03/04/laravel-learning-resources/)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnlaravel/)
- [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) (Screen Casts)
- [Learninglaravel](http://learninglaravel.net/resources) with [Free eBook](http://learninglaravel.net/)
- [culttt](http://culttt.com/search/?q=laravel)
- [Laravel-recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/)
- [Laravel-tricks](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/)
- [Heera.IT -  (Laravel Tag)](http://heera.it/tag/laravel)

Also check the [Laravel Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Also there is a live web chat here http://laravel.io/chat for the IRC chanel #laravel at FreeNode

Comment: All about Laracasts: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the question I think you could find useful this link

[What's a PHP framework and what's a good one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301240/whats-a-php-framework-and-whats-a-good-one)

Why to use Laravel?
Laravel let you write a PHP app very fast, there are some generators for resources, controllers and models, also you can use blade the template engine. Did you hear about ruby on rails (ROR), laravel is somewhat similar to ROR and also are cheaper to implement becouse every hosting has PHP support. So if you can't afford a VPS for rails development then Laravel is a good choice.

For UI Enhancement you should look for a CSS framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) the integration of these CSS frameworks very straightforward.

The Laravel installation it's very easy look at the quickstart from documentation http://laravel.com/docs/quick and this free laracast video https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-installation-for-newbs

Also as @WereWolf mention there are a lot of resources to learn, [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony2/info) or [Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/info) does not have as many learning resources as Laravel.